# OS X Catalina: update_terminal_cwd:11: unrecognized modifier `i'

Tags: zsh, bashrc, macos-catalina

In .zshrc be sure to have

```
# .zshrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/zshrc ]; then
    . /etc/zshrc
fi
```

instead of

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

In order to avoid

```
/etc/bashrc:8: command not found: shopt
/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal:172: parse error near `;'
update_terminal_cwd:11: unrecognized modifier `i'
```

annoying message. I still don't understand why it involves an unrecognized modifier `i'.
From where the error really comes from? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have either of those statements in your `.zshrc` file.

`/etc/zshrc` will get sourced automatically by Zsh *before* sourcing `.zshrc`.

And in Zsh, you should never source any files that have the word `bash` in their name. Those are meant to be sourced in Bash, not Zsh.